# Statechart for javascript like Sproutcore's statechart?

Tags: javascript, yui, yui3, sproutcore, statechart

In Sproutcore there is a statechart framework I can use for giving the application states which holds actions for what you can do in different states.

I wonder if there is a similar standalone statechart framework I can use outside Sproutcore eg. in conjunction with YUI3.

Comment: Ki (the SC statechart framework) is pretty awesome....it would be nice if one could use it outside of SC...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were about ten days early asking the question. [Michael Cohen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/521786/michael-cohen) found this: https://github.com/jakesgordon/javascript-state-machine/ which appears to have surfaced June 1.

Answer (score 4):

There is a framework called Stativus:

https://github.com/etgryphon/stativus

It is essentially the factored out version of Sproutcore state chart framework. I'm using it on the project and quite happy with it.

Documentation is unfortunately too simplistic, however library is quite small and easy to use. I'm working on the blog post about it right now, it will be posted in my blog http://zubairov.posterous.com soon.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this, which should also do the job: https://github.com/jbeard4/SCION

Answer (score 0):

FSM !== Statecharts. I wrote an answer about comparison of FSM and Statecharts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10769231/1419423)

Answer (score 0):

As I posted in another question, there is also [statechart](https://github.com/DavidDurman/statechart) by David Durman.
And, a new one: xstate, https://github.com/davidkpiano/xstate