# More Javascript statechart frameworks

Tags: javascript, statechart

I'm using ExtJS and think it's an amazing framework. However, they don't have a statechart built in which makes app development depending on states very painful.

I recently found this one:

https://github.com/jakesgordon/javascript-state-machine

It seems like a very solid statechart for JS applications.

I wonder if there are other frameworks like this so that I can compare before I settle with which to use.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like [Javascript Finite State Machine (v2.0.0)](https://github.com/jakesgordon/javascript-state-machine) as well.

A few others I have not tried:

- [Ki](https://github.com/FrozenCanuck/Ki)
- [SproutCore](http://blog.sproutcore.com/statecharts-in-sproutcore/)
- [Stativus](https://github.com/etgryphon/stativus)

Which one did you settle for?

Comment: I settled with all of them :) SproutCore Blossom is using Ki (which is the same as SproutCore's statechart). There is a chance they will use Stativus instead under the hood in the future.

Answer (score 11):

Things like [JS Statemachine](https://github.com/jakesgordon/javascript-state-machine) are fundamentally different than Statecharts.  They are really a superset of FSM.  If you are doing a sproutcore-based application, the native Statecharts are good (a little verbose imho).  If you are using another framework or rolling your own javascript, [Stativus](http://www.stativ.us) is really the only full featured statechart framework out there.  Stativus can be used in any javascript framework: Backbone.js, ember.js, SproutCore, batman.js, ExtJS, Sencha etc...

With FSM, you don't get:

- Parallel States
- Nested Substates
- History States
- Statechart Event Propagation

Its really like trying to drag race a Yugo with a Ferrari.  They both can get you places and have four wheels, but one has so much more power that it isn't even a competition.

caveat:  I helped write the original statechart implementation for SproutCore and I wrote Stativus...

Comment: Thanks for this, stativ.us looks promising, although, still very much in alpha (docs and site seems buggy). While it is true that a state chart is an extension of FSM, it not that different, and if all you require is four wheels to get from A to B without the pomp.. then JS Statemachine is a useful pragmatic solution.

Comment: I'm just getting to the site and documentation. The underlying code is pretty solid and is being used in a couple of production sites.  If you find bugs, please tell me...

Comment: The lack of Stativus documentation is really holding back adoption IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

Another Statechart implementation in JavaScript is [statechart](https://github.com/DavidDurman/statechart) by David Durman.

one more: Machine.js, based on "behavior trees".  http://machinejs.maryrosecook.com/

New one: xstate, https://github.com/davidkpiano/xstate

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [javascript-state-machine](https://github.com/jakesgordon/javascript-state-machine), and liking it quite a lot. The only gotcha I came across is trying to use the Asynchronous State Transitions. Be sure to use them on entering or leaving **states**. Not before or after **events**. With that, everything is working well. A solid tool so far.